# Dual monitor with different screen resoultion

Tags: linux, gnu-screen, xrandr, pop-os

I have bought a secondary monitor for my laptop its **18-inch** monitor with a resolution of **1366x7688**. My Laptop is **15-inch** monitor with a screen resolution of **1920 x 1080**. I am using a **pop os** on my laptop. I am not able to scale both as exactly as one. I want my secondary display to be normal independent of scaling if I open a chrome tab on my laptop and one on a dual monitor I need to scroll to the bottom on my secondary monitor

[image: Display from settings]